# Deleting visible duplicates of visible rows only

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

New at VBA. I am using the code below to identify and delete rows in Sheet1 which have duplicate values in Column C of Sheet2, but I need the code to **not** delete rows that are already hidden from a filter.

I have searched around and tried using .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) but I don't know where to place it. Another option I thought was using EntireRow.Hidden syntax but I am not sure how to incorporate that either.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim FoundDup As Range

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    For Row = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

    Set FoundDup = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C").Find(Cells(Row, 3), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)


    If Not FoundDup Is Nothing Then
        Cells(Row, 3).EntireRow.Delete
    End If


    Next Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If the solution worked, please mark the answer as accepted. (Click the check mark next to it.) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra condition to your `If` statement:

`If Not FoundDup Is Nothing And Not Cells(Row,3).EntireRow.Hidden Then`